# Identify some files in Specialized.StringCollection

Tags: vb.net

I read the *.fileExt files using:

```
Dim tempList As New Specialized.StringCollection
         tempList.AddRange(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path, subFolders, "*" & fileExt).ToArray)
```

When processing I find some files that were deleted and are invisible from the file explorer but that are read by `.GetFiles`, they have their original name preceded by: "~$"

Example: "C:.......\~$OriginalFileName.fileExt"

I tried to exclude files that have "~$" at the beginning of the name, but it's not a good solution since I can create and save a file with "~$" at the beginning of the name, then the code would avoid a file that was never deleted.

I want to continue using `.AddRange` and exclude deleted files, I see two options:

- Prevent `.GetFiles` from taking those files.
- Identify them in `tempList` to avoid processing them.

I can't get any of the two to work.

I guess there is a simple way to identify if a file is deleted or not... an attribute or flag that identifies it as "deleted"... but I don't know how to do it. It's possible? How I should proceed?

Comment: Those ~$ files aren't deleted, they are probably orphaned backup files from whatever program is used to edit the file. Would it be sufficient if it did not include hidden files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help you:

```
  tempList As New Specialized.StringCollection
            tempList.AddRange((From sFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path, subFolders, "*" & fileExt).ToList.AsEnumerable
                               Where sFile IsNot Nothing
                               Where sFile.IndexOf("~$") = -1).ToArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

Some programs create a backup file while a file is being edited, and those files are named starting with "~$" and have the hidden attribute set. Sometimes those files get orphaned, perhaps because of a program crash, but you don't notice them because they are hidden.

To avoid getting hidden files, you can select only files which do not have the hidden attribute, something like this:

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer On

Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim srcDir = "C:\temp\testfiles"
        Dim fileExt = ".txt"

        Dim tempList As New Specialized.StringCollection()

        Dim selectedFiles = (New DirectoryInfo(srcDir)).GetFileSystemInfos("*" & fileExt).
            Where(Function(fi) Not (fi.Attributes And FileAttributes.Hidden) = FileAttributes.Hidden).
            Select(Function(fi) fi.FullName)

        tempList.AddRange(selectedFiles.ToArray())

        For Each s In tempList
            Console.WriteLine(s)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

I created some files in a directory, and one of them I named starting with "~$" *and* set its hidden attribute:

```
C:\temp\testfiles>dir
 Directory of C:\temp\testfiles

21/10/2019  15:48                 0 one.txt
21/10/2019  15:49                 0 two.txt
21/10/2019  15:48                 0 ~$one.txt
               3 File(s)              0 bytes

C:\temp\testfiles>dir /a:h

 Directory of C:\temp\testfiles

21/10/2019  15:49                 0 ~$three.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
```

and got this output from the program:

> C:\temp\testfiles\one.txt
>   C:\temp\testfiles\two.txt
>   C:\temp\testfiles\~$one.txt

N.B. You are probably making things difficult for yourself by using a Specialized.StringCollection() instead of a `List(Of String)`.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I will try to use your solution.